Wilcoxon paired test, with 0s in the dataset
I am aiming to test the frequency of behaviours (of guinea a pigs) during the first 5 minutes, and last 5 minutes. This does mean the data has a higher number of 0s throughout.
The data is non normal, and mostly contains outliers (depending on the behaviour, I am testing each behaviour separately)
I am trying to run a wilcoxons paired test, but am struggling because of the 0s. Is there a way around this, or a better test to run?
Here's a data set im having the most trouble with, as it consists of mainly 0s

Here is another example of a behaviour with less 0s, but again is causing the same issue.

Thank you

Is this the whole data set or a sample? Also, it seems like first and last are integers. Is that always the case?

This is the whole sample for one of the behaviours (there are 15 in total, each broken down into its own excel sheet to be analysed individually), yes first and last are always integers

Not much hope with essentially constant data. What do the numbers represent?

They represent how often a behaviour is displayed within a time period, first being the first 5 minutes of the investigation, last being the last five minutes

Is there any "intervention", stimulus, "treatment" applied to the guinea pigs between the first and last 5 minutes, which leads you to expect that some behaviors would be more/less frequent? Having said this, that one single example has exactly 0 chance of ever being significant, no matter what test; basically, you observed 1 individual which showed a change. N=1 is not amenable to any statistics.

The animals were exposed to a handing session within a farm park, so there was an expected change to happen within the behaviours. I can include another example of a behaviour which contains a few less 0s.

The problem is that there is very little variation, so there is very little to analyze. This is compounded by the small sample. Sorry, but I don't see a good way to go here except to get a lot more data.

I'd expect the Wilcoxon paired test to give you insignificant results here, which should be correct in the sense that these data don't show clear evidence for any systematic difference (this depends on continuity correction to do a proper job here which may require some thought).

Some software doesn't discard the zeros and ties, so you may be able to get exact results, but you are unlikely to get significance with this data. See Pratt, J. W. 1959. Remarks on zeros and ties in the Wilcoxon signed rank procedures. Journal of the American
Statistical Association 54: 655–667. https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.1959.10501526.
